# How do I convert a .NET console application to a Winforms or WPF application

Tags: .net, winforms, console

I frequently start with a simple console application to try out an idea, then create a new GUI based project and copy the code in. Is there a better way? Can I convert my existing console application easily?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Just add a new Winform, add the following code to your `Main`:

```
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Also, be sure the `[STAThread]` attribute is declared above your `Main` function to indicate the COM threading model your Windows application will use (more about STAThread [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0jPzb9kk3o)).

Then right click your project and select properties and change the "Output type" to Windows application and you're done.

**EDIT :**

In VS2008 the property to change is Application type

[image]

Comment: If your app is using the Compact Framework then you only need to add `Application.Run(new Form1());`. The first two lines are not valid.

Comment: Don't forget to add `[STAThreadAttribute]` to your `Main` method definition.

Answer (score 30):

For completeness - and for other newbs like me - you also need to add:

using System.Windows.Forms;

... to the top of Program.cs

Comment: Also add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.