# Converting Console Application to Windows Application in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, console-application, windows

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144701/how-do-i-convert-a-net-console-application-to-a-winforms-or-wpf-application) which works, but I find it hard to believe there isn't a one-click solution to this problem.

Do you know a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a "better" way. This is really the only way :) (unless you create your own project converter).

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way. You could, I guess, edit the project files by hand to add references, but I would stick with the IDE.