# Porting console app to winforms C#, static types error

Tags: c#, winforms, static, console

I made a nice little console app with some 3rd party libraries and stuff.
But now I want to port it to winforms.
I just copy everything from the console to a new class in the winforms, removed the main and hoped it would work.

But no.

I just get the error `static types cannot be used as parameters` in some of my functions.
Said functions work perfectly well in my console app. And the parameter used in the functions are all from a 3rd party mouse-control library.

What am I missing? : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change your existing project into a Winforms project - see [How do I convert a .NET console application to a Winforms or WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144701/how-do-i-convert-a-net-console-application-to-a-winforms-or-wpf-application)

Answer (score 3):

Remove static keyword from all your declarations. I'm sure that you put them there to make sure that your static main function for the console app would be able do directly access them. Now as you don't have a static main function, you don't need the static types anymore.

Comment: Yeah tried that, the problem lies outside my code.
Its a 3rd party library i use for controlling the mouse which give me errors.

Comment: Then try to use static caller functions for the code that you don't have any control over, if you're sure that problem is not your code.

Comment: Yes but application and UI threads are separate so trying to run things on the static entry method would make console->winforms transition meaningless as there would be no UI on the main thread.