# Debug console C++ program without closing the window automatically in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 closes console window in after my C++ console program has finished. Is it possible to ask for a key press instead, while

- not modifying the source code of the program. (Writing `system("pause")` surrounded by the proper `#if`s at the end of *every* program is not a solution I call elegant.)
- running the program in debug mode. (The "magic" key `Ctrl+F5` works, but that runs the program without debugging)
- not using breakpoints. (So far the best solution is to put a breakpoint at the end of the main function but that solution is not really convenient either.)

I know that this has been asked many times before (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775865/preventing-console-window-from-closing-on-visual-studio-c-c-console-applicatio)) but neither answers satisfy the requirements above.

If there is no way to do this than I'm interested in why the feature was removed as clearly a lot of users miss it and say that it worked in previous versions. Also it seems that there are some users who [does not want it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897736/avoiding-press-any-key-to-continue-when-running-console-application-from-visua). A configuration option or plugin would be nice.

Comment: What about a break point at the `main()` functions `return` statement of last closing brace `}`?

Comment: That's the working solution I mention in the third bullet point but it requires too many clicks to close the application in my opinion.