# How to close the console window after the program?

Tags: c++, console, termination

I'm trying to make a program which will **close the console window** after execution. But it outputs this instead:

```
(the program output)
--------------------------------
Process exited after 15.7973 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't want to see this message, I just want to make the program which will **completely close the window**.

End of my program:

```
   ...
   if(getch==116){
     ...
   }
   system("pause >nul");
   return 0;
}
```

I'm using Dev-C++.

Comment: Looks like you're using an IDE, which one are you using?

Comment: Remove `system("pause >nul");` Run program directly, without IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console window is normally closed when you run your exe with a double-click outside of IDE, or when run in debug mode with F5.
Avoid the use of system("pause") or system("pause > NULL").
[Avoiding "Press any key to continue" when running console application from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897736/avoiding-press-any-key-to-continue-when-running-console-application-from-visua)

Comment: "The console window is normally closed when you run your exe with a double-click outside of IDE" -> That's the reason?? Really?? Anyways, thank you! :-)
Btw. I'm using DevC++, not Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
system("pause >nul");
```

Comment: @Waterflame: The `pause` system command is what keeps the window open and waits for input.