# breaking out a loop in c#

Tags: c#, loops

I am having trouble figuring out how to break out of a loop that contains a switch statement.
i need to press 0 twice to exit the console why?
how can i fix it to exit from the first time

```
public void Start()
{
    int choice = 0;
    bool trueNumber = false;

    do
    {
        ShowMenu(); // display the menu
        Console.Write("Your Choice : ");
        trueNumber = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out choice);        

        if (!trueNumber)
            Console.WriteLine("Your Choice must be an integer. Try again.");

        switch (choice) // select the relevant function based on user input
        {
            case 1:
                CalculateCelsiusToFahrenheit();
                break;
            case 2:
                CalculateFahrenheitToCelsius();
                break;
            case 0:
                return;     // exit when i press 0          
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option: Choose 0, 1, or 2 Thank you ");
                break;
        }
    } while (choice != 0);
}
```

Comment: FYI: `TryParse` will set `choice` to 0 if the supplied text is not a valid number.

Comment: What's the code that calls `Start()` ?

Comment: This looks fine regarding the exiting. If the user inputs ZERO, it will exit. You can replace the `return` with a simple `break` as it will break out of the do-while loop since `choice == 0`.

Comment: _"i need to press 0 twice to exit the console why?"_ - do you happen to start the program from the IDE (Visual Studio). Depending on settings, VS adds a "keep open until key pressed" for you. Could that be what you are seeing here? Try to build in Release mode and execute the .exe from cmd-line.

Comment: I just ran your code and it works perfectly fine..

Comment: @PeterHenry yes but when i press 0 as the first option it did not exit until i press 0 again

Comment: The only difference is that I commented out ShowMenu().. Is this prompting the user to enter a number? Because it will then do it again 2 lines later..

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this from an IDE (like Visual Studio), the default behavior for console applications is to end with a "Press any key to continue." so it waits with the output displayed.

related answer: [VS setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897736/avoiding-press-any-key-to-continue-when-running-console-application-from-visua)