# How to convert Console application to winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to do some changes here, I want to convert this application to winforms. And i want to store these output into a text file, How can I do it? please help

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
public static class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
     // Create a Timer object that knows to call our TimerCallback
  // method once every 2000 milliseconds.
  Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 1000);
  // Wait for the user to hit <Enter>
   Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void TimerCallback(Object o) 
{
   // Display the date/time when this method got called.
  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
  // Force a garbage collection to occur for this demo.
  GC.Collect();
 }
}
```

Output of this application.

[image]
Source [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186084/how-do-you-add-a-timer-to-a-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: here's the conversoin Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144701/how-do-i-convert-a-net-console-application-to-a-winforms-or-wpf-application

Comment: and here's the writing to text part: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: its not working, i want change it grammatically...

Comment: BTW can I ask why you simply TOOK the code from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186084/how-do-you-add-a-timer-to-a-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: From amount of content in your console software, best and easiest is to create a new project and copy relevant peaces of code from old console project into new shiny winform's one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to application `>` and change is Application type to `Winform` and then point start up object at `Sub Main`

Comment: tried but not opening..!

Comment: I'm sorry for my language, i mean its not working. Now i found another method to do that. How can i close this question?

Comment: mark any one answer as Answer... Thats it

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the solution and select "Add Reference"
Select System.Windows.Forms and hit OK

Comment: it already added. Or i simply create new one?