# C# Console App as a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, console-application

I started a project as a console app in visual studios and I'm now finding that I need a UI (form) but when I run the program it beings up a console. Is there anyway of having my Program.cs code from  my console app run from a button event?

Spinet of my Code:

```
    using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
public class Program
{

    public static string name = null;
    public static string userloc = null;
    public static string protocol = null;

    public static int Portal = 43;
    public static string Address = "whois.net.dcs.hull.ac.uk";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (args[i])
            {
                case "-h0":
                    protocol = "-h0";
                    break;

                case "-h1":
                    protocol = "-h1";
                    break;

                case "-p":
                    Portal = int.Parse(args[i + 1]);
                    ++i;
                    break;
```

Form Code:

```
namespace location
{
    public partial class Location : Form
    {
        public Location()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void updateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be an option to have two programs (one console, one form)? And then the former launches the latter?

Comment: Perhaps this question may help [How do I convert a .NET console application to a Winforms or WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144701/how-do-i-convert-a-net-console-application-to-a-winforms-or-wpf-application)

Comment: mjwills that would not be ideal unfortunately, but thank you.

Comment: DeanOC that seems to be along the right path, however, I'm confused as to how I can have my button on my form run the Main() code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what you require is at [How do I convert a .NET console application to a Winforms or WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144701/how-do-i-convert-a-net-console-application-to-a-winforms-or-wpf-application).

You have then asked in comments "how I can have my button on my form run the Main() code?". I'm assuming you know that the `updateBtn_Click` method will get executed when `updateBtn` is clicked, and I'm assuming that's the button you're referring to as "my button on my form".

The answer is that you wouldn't want to have the button click call `Program.Main`, since that is the entry point for the application.

I'm also assuming that you want to keep the command line parameters, so you need to leave the processing of `args` in `Program.Main`.

Whatever the rest of your functionality is, you could move it directly into your form, into the `updateBtn_Click` method. The code may need to be tweaked to get the values of the command line parameters from there by prefixing their names with `Program.` since they are all static (e.g. `Program.Portal`).

This will probably satisfy your requirements for now. Over time, you will realise that cramming code into "code behind" (which is what I've just told you to do) isn't a great idea. If you Refactor your code, then you would be able to use your functionality from the command line, or the WinForm app, or maybe a WPF or Web app. But maybe it's good enough for now...